# Added a Field to WeBlog Entry template, trying to get the field in Category.ascx.cs

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, weblog

I have followed the steps in the following link [Template Settings](https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/wiki/Template-Settings) and created custom templates for Entry, Comment and Category. To the Custom Entry Template, I have added an additional field. I have a requirement to display it in the Categories.ascx. I am able to override the Categories.ascx but I am unable to get the value of the added field using WeBlog's API. Here's the code that I am using. But the issue is that the Class EntryItem doesn't have the additional field that I have added. Is there a way to read this field using WeBlog API?

```csharp
EntryItem[] blogEntries = ManagerFactory.EntryManagerInstance.GetBlogEntries();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EntryItem` inherits from `CustomItem` I believe, so you can use the `InnerItem` Property to get access to the actual Item. Your field should then be available like this:

```csharp
 entryItem.InnerITem["YouField"];
```

You can use a field renderer in the `Categories.ascx` file to display the value of you field and use data binding to get the item assigned to the field renderer.

```
 <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer1" runat="server" FieldName="YourField"  item='<%# entryItem.innerItem %>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Categories.ascx` you can add this code to render the new field on the front-end:

```
<sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Your New Field Name" ID="frNewField" runat="server" />
```

Then in the C# code-behind, add this code to data bind the front-end field renderer to the entry item's underlying Sitecore item:

```
frNewField.Item = entryItem.InnerItem;
```